# How to prevent empty string (sent with Axios) replaced by null value (received by Laravel API)?

Tags: laravel, axios

I'm sending an Axios request like below:

```
$axios.post('user', { foo: this.foo })
```

where `this.foo` is an object:

```
{
  name: 'John',
  abc: '',
  def: null
}
```

It's calling my Laravel API, and when I log `$request->all()`, `abc` is received as `NULL` value instead of **empty string**:

```
"foo" => 
  array (
    name => "John",
    abc => NULL,
    def => NULL
  )
```

How should I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is defined by `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class`

You can pass callback function for check when this middleware must not transform string to null

```
ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::skipWhen(function (Request $request){
  //your logic to skip this request - return true when skip is needed
});
```

Put this in AppServiceProvider::boot() method.